# How Do I Create Dot Matrix Digits using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

How can I produce 5 x 7 dot matrix type digits for a clock project?

Here's an example of what I'm looking for.

[image: Dot Matrix Digits]

I manually coded the position of each dot in each digit.

**Is there a better way to create dot matrix digits**?

By better I mean easier to code, easier to verify, makes use of existing fonts or other components, or anything else an experienced Swing developer might consider as an important consideration.

The rest of this question is the context for the naysayers that claim I didn't put enough effort into formulating my question.

Since I'm providing an answer to this question, I'm not posting fake bad code in the question.  Sure, we appreciate it when people show their efforts.  The code and text in my answer should supplement the question, in my opinion.

A few days ago, as I'm writing this, someone posted a question about making a clock with dot-matrix digits.  The person posting the question provided code and a picture of what they had created. The person had created a `BufferedImage` where they had hardcoded the position of each square dot in his 4 x 7 dot matrix digits.

I was impressed with how much work the person had put into his `BufferedImage`, so I went off to my Eclipse to figure out how to generalize what he had done.

While I was away, people commented and closed his question.  By the time I got back with my answer, the person had deleted his question.

Since I had what I thought was a good answer, I searched for an appropriate question.  When I didn't find an appropriate question, I created a question.

Sure, I focused more on my answer than my question.  Silly me, I thought that the answer would help provide context for the question.

Well, I hope that this explanation sheds some more light on why I thought this topic was important enough to create a question and ask for answers.

Comment: I found a [5 x 7 Font](https://www.1001fonts.com/5by7-font.html) you could download. From a quick glance it looks like a 10pt size will give you a one-to-one mapping of each pixel. So using Andrews concept you might be able to paint the character to a BufferedImage and then check which pixel has been painted to populate your 2D matrix. It would be less involved since you don't need to worry about scaling.

Comment: Hi Gilbert, where's the code that results in this output? What do you mean by "better way" (in objective terms)? We need more information for this to be on-topic.

Comment: @TylerH: I was trying to create a question and answers that would serve as a reference.  I suppose I can no longer provide a question with an answer.  Oh, well.

Comment: @TylerH, How is this opinion based??? There is no more information needed to answer the question. The OP provided an explicit question with one approach to solving the problem. The OP stated the solution was based on "manually" coding all the information and is looking for a better way, where better would imply "not manual". The forum allows people to ask a question and post a solution, which was done. It also give people a chance to provide alternative solutions, which is not longer possible. I was just about to provide my solution based on my original comment.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, I have a solution based on my original comment. Since I can't add an answer, I could edit your question and post my code. You could then copy and remove my code to restore the question. Let me know if you are interested? Note the solution is only as could as the Font. I like the design of your digits better. So my solution won't look like yours, but if you are able to find a Font you like it might help.

Comment: @camickr: Sure, go ahead and edit the question.  As I said, I wanted this question to be a reference with lots of different answers.  I don't necessarily think my answer is the best.

Comment: @camickr I didn't vote to close it as opinion-based. I voted to close it as 'Needs details or clarity'. However, the "better way" is an opinion-based question, so I understand why the other two CVers used that reason.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Of course you can provide self-answered questions still. However, the requirement for them, as it always has been, is that the question provides enough information for *other people* to answer it just as accurately. Of course you can provide an answer to your own question because you have all the information. You can provide alternative solutions to problems with your code because you have your code. Other users can only guess because... you haven't included the code in the question. Nor have you really explained what's problematic about the code you wrote.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, code added to your question.

Comment: @TylerH, there was enough information for others to answer the question. Andrew already provided an answer and I was about to provide an answer. If it is not clear enough for you, then skip it! Why do you feel you need to close the question even when the question had TWO answer before it was closed? This question and answers allowed for a discussion for those that are interested. Just because you are not interested is no reason to stop others from contributing. My solution was based on Andrews solution. Seeing his approach allowed me to expand my thinking. Is that not what the forum is about?

Comment: @camickr And Andrew's answer begins by saying it's a guess at meeting the requirements. *That's the problem*, we don't know the details of OP's situation beyond "it's hardcoded" or what OP means by "better". "Still hardcoded" is OP's solution so it doesn't seem like "not hardcoded" counts? What about partially hardcoded? We need OP's criteria for 'better' to know. Finally, please do not edit solutions into the question. The question is for questions, not answers. (oh, and Stack Overflow is not a forum)

Comment: @TylerH, please don't remove code that is not your own. I asked Gilbert permission to add my solution since you left no alternative. If the OP knew what "better" meant why would they ask a question? They are looking for suggestions or different approaches. They posted a working example to prove they have spent time looking at the problem. Seeing other suggestions can help spur discussion. It allows the OP (or others) to see new approaches. Andrew's suggestion was the basis of my suggestion. I am here to promote the exchange of ideas, not prevent them.

Comment: @camickr it doesn't matter whether you have OP's permission or not (you don't need it to make an edit in general). What matters is the content you are adding. In this case, you're adding an answer. That belongs in the answer section. However, the question is closed, so it looks like you're just trying to circumvent the site rules in order to get some answer content posted.

Comment: At least I try to provide answers. Do you? I am doing what I can to pass on information. Gilbert is aware of this and will remove the edit once the information is received. Why are you so against people sharing ideas and suggestions?

Comment: @camickr If Gilbert is going to remove the edit then why rollback? It's already there in the revision history.

Comment: @camickr sorry, but solutions do not belong in a question. When there is a dispute over the content of a post, please don’t enter into an edit war either, that’s not a good use of anyone’s time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, 1) a question was asked (and answered) by a regular Swing contributor that intrigued me, although I did not have a suggestion. 2) overnight an alternate approach was given that sparked another approach in my mind. 3) I spent time testing the alternate approach and it seemed reasonably successful. 4) I was about to post my solution "as an answer" but couldn't because the question was recently closed by some individual who posts an answer maybe once or twice a month didn't like the wording of the question.

Comment: 5) Not wanting my time and effort to go to waste I asked the OP if they wanted me to edit the question (temporarily) and post my solution. 6) The OP agreed, so I did just that. 7) Then this individual who hasn't contributed any time or effort to the question removes the edit without the knowledge of the OP. 8) I restored the edit, because the information is for the OP. 8) You then lock the question. 9) Good job on limiting the free flow of information and ideas.
10) I agree, our time can be better spent helping one another, not preventing people from helping.

Comment: @camickr then why not spend a bit of time *first* making the question worthy of reopening? Or, alternatively, craft a similar but on-topic question you can then self-answer. Those are more productive ways of helping not just this one question asker but *future visitors with a similar problem*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, The most productive way is to NOT close the question in the first place, then all visitors (now and in the future) can benefit. The question was open for almost a day before it was closed, indicating most people who read the question did NOT have a problem with it. It was closed even though it contained multiple complete answers. Updating the question is not a productive use of my time since questions rarely get re-opened. Also, It is not my place to edit others thoughts. Creating a new question is not a good idea because now the information is contained in two places.

Comment: @camickr: No, the question, as it stands, is off topic. It is *way* too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to code the position of each dot in each digit.

However, you can do this in a flexible way.

Here's what I mean.  A 5 x 7 dot matrix digit can be represented as a two-dimensional `int` array.  It could also be represented as a `boolean` array, but a matrix of 0 and 1 values is easier to visually verify.

As an example. here's a method to code the zero digit.  You can see that the ones create a visual outline that can be easily verified.

```
    private int[][] defineZeroMatrix() {
        int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
        matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
        matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
        matrix[2] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
        matrix[3] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
        matrix[4] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
        matrix[5] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
        matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
        
        return matrix;
    }
```

It took me about 15 minutes to code all of the dot matrix digit matrices.

It's possible to code a dot matrix digit using a sparse matrix.  Unfortunately, that idea leads to more code that's visually harder to verify.

Here's an example of the dot matrix digit two coded as a sparse matrix of coordinates.

```
    private Point[] defineTwoCoordinates() {
        Point[] array = new Point[14];
        array[0] = new Point(0, 1);
        array[1] = new Point(1, 0);
        array[2] = new Point(2, 0);
        array[3] = new Point(3, 0);
        array[4] = new Point(4, 1);
        array[5] = new Point(4, 2);
        array[6] = new Point(3, 3);
        array[7] = new Point(2, 4);
        array[8] = new Point(1, 5);
        array[9] = new Point(0, 6);
        array[10] = new Point(1, 6);
        array[11] = new Point(2, 6);
        array[12] = new Point(3, 6);
        array[13] = new Point(4, 6);
        
        return array;
    }
```

After we've coded all of the digit matrices, we'll create an array of matrices.

```
    private int[][][] matrices;
```

The leftmost index is the digit, from 0 to 9.  The second index is the row of the digit matrix.  The third index is the column of the digit matrix.

Finally, we extend a `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method to actually paint the dot matrix digit.

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        g.setColor(dotColor);
        for (int row = 0; row < matrices[digit].length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < matrices[digit][row].length; column++) {
                if (matrices[digit][row][column] != 0) {
                    int x = margin + column * pixelWidth;
                    int y = margin + row * pixelWidth;
                    g.fillOval(x, y, dotWidth, dotWidth);
                }
            }               
        }
    }
```

Here's a complete runnable example of how you would create a dot matrix digit panel by extending a `JPanel`, and use several dot matrix digit panels to create whatever GUI you want.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DotMatrixDigits implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DotMatrixDigits());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dot Matrix Digits");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(defineTopPanel(), BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        frame.add(defineBottomPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel defineTopPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(0, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(1, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(2, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(3, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(4, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel defineBottomPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(5, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(6, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(7, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(8, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(new DotMatrixDigit(9, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK));
        return panel;
    }
    
    /**
     * <p>
     * The <code>DotMatrixDigit</code> class creates a dot-matrix digit panel by
     * extending <code>JPanel</code>. The dot matrix digit is 5 positions across and
     * 7 positions down. The size of the dot and distance between dots are defined
     * in the constructor of this class. The shape of the dot is determined in the
     * <code>paintComponent</code> method.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @author Gilbert G. Le Blanc
     * @version 1.8 - 20 October 2020
     *
     * @see JPanel
     * @see Color
     */
    public class DotMatrixDigit extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        /** int field to hold the digit to display **/
        private int digit;
        
        /** int field to hold the width of the dot in pixels **/
        private int dotWidth;
        
        /** int field to hold the distance between the 
         * top left corner of the dots in pixels **/
        private int pixelWidth;
        
        /** int field to hold the margin size in 
         * pixels surrounding the digit **/
        private int margin;
        
        private final Color dotColor;
        
        private int[][][] matrices;
        
        /**
         * <p>
         * This constructor creates a dot matrix digit panel. The preferred size of the
         * panel is determined by the pixel width of each dot, including the space
         * between the dots.
         * </p>
         * 
         * @param digit           - The initial digit to display from 0 through 9.
         * @param dotColor        - The <code>Color</code> of the dots.
         * @param backgroundColor - The background <code>Color</code> of the dot matrix
         *                        digit panel.
         *                        
         */
        public DotMatrixDigit(int digit, Color dotColor, Color backgroundColor) {
            this.digit = digit;
            this.dotColor = dotColor;
            
            this.dotWidth = 10;
            this.pixelWidth = 15;
            this.margin = dotWidth;
            this.matrices = defineDigitMatricies();
            
            int width = 4 * pixelWidth + dotWidth + margin + margin;
            int height = 6 * pixelWidth + dotWidth + margin + margin;
            this.setBackground(backgroundColor);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        }
        
        private int[][][] defineDigitMatricies() {
            int[][][] matrices = new int[10][][];
            matrices[0] = defineZeroMatrix();
            matrices[1] = defineOneMatrix();
            matrices[2] = defineTwoMatrix();
            matrices[3] = defineThreeMatrix();
            matrices[4] = defineFourMatrix();
            matrices[5] = defineFiveMatrix();
            matrices[6] = defineSixMatrix();
            matrices[7] = defineSevenMatrix();
            matrices[8] = defineEightMatrix();
            matrices[9] = defineNineMatrix();
            
            return matrices;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineZeroMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            
            return matrix;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineOneMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            
            return matrix;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineTwoMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            
            return matrix;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineThreeMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            
            return matrix;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineFourMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
            
            return matrix;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineFiveMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            
            return matrix;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineSixMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            
            return matrix;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineSevenMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
            
            return matrix;
        }
        
        private int[][] defineEightMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            
            return matrix;
        }

        private int[][] defineNineMatrix() {
            int[][] matrix = new int[7][];
            matrix[0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[2] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[3] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            matrix[4] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[5] = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            matrix[6] = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
            
            return matrix;
        }

        /**
         * <p>
         * The <code>setDigit</code> method sets the digit to display and repaints the
         * panel.
         * </p>
         * 
         * @param digit - A digit from 0 through 9.
         */
        public void setDigit(int digit) {
            this.digit = digit;
            this.repaint();
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            g.setColor(dotColor);
            for (int row = 0; row < matrices[digit].length; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < matrices[digit][row].length; column++) {
                    if (matrices[digit][row][column] != 0) {
                        int x = margin + column * pixelWidth;
                        int y = margin + row * pixelWidth;
                        g.fillOval(x, y, dotWidth, dotWidth);
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better way to create dot matrix digits?

Don't know if 'better' (depends on whether effort or accuracy is the primary consideration) but there is a way to *calculate* the array based on the `Shape` of the digit.

Here is the result for a (bold) version of the default Monospaced font on this machine.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FontToDotMatrix {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    Shape[] shapes = new Shape[10];
    JComboBox fonts;
    PixelArray[] pixelArrays = new PixelArray[10];

    FontToDotMatrix() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        String[] fontFamilies = GraphicsEnvironment.
                getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        fonts = new JComboBox(fontFamilies);
        ui.add(fonts, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JPanel digitPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 5, 4, 4));
        ui.add(digitPanel);
        digitPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
            PixelArray pixelArray = new PixelArray();
            pixelArrays[ii] = pixelArray;
            digitPanel.add(pixelArray);
        }

        ActionListener listener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
                pixelArrays[ii].updatePixels(getLitPixels("" + ii));
            }
        };
        fonts.addActionListener(listener);
        fonts.setSelectedItem("Monospaced");
    }

    private Shape moveShapeToCenter(Shape shape) {
        int w = 50;
        int h = 70;
        Rectangle2D b = shape.getBounds2D();
        double xOff = -b.getX() + ((w - b.getWidth()) / 2d);
        double yOff = -b.getY() + ((h - b.getHeight()) / 2d);
        AffineTransform move = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(xOff, yOff);
        return move.createTransformedShape(shape);
    }

    private boolean[][] getLitPixels(String digit) {
        Font font = new Font(fonts.getSelectedItem().toString(), Font.BOLD, 70);
        Shape shape = getShapeOfCharacter(font, digit);
        Rectangle2D rect = shape.getBounds2D();
        double h = rect.getHeight();
        double ratio = 70d / h;
        AffineTransform scale = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(ratio, ratio);
        shape = moveShapeToCenter(scale.createTransformedShape(shape));
        boolean[][] bools = new boolean[5][7];
        for (int yy = 0; yy < 7; yy++) {
            for (int xx = 0; xx < 5; xx++) {
                Point point = new Point((xx * 10) + 5, (yy * 10) + 5);
                bools[xx][yy] = shape.contains(point);
            }
        }
        return bools;
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    private Shape getShapeOfCharacter(Font font, String digit) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
        GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, digit);

        return gv.getOutline();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            FontToDotMatrix o = new FontToDotMatrix();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class PixelArray extends JPanel {

    JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[5][7];

    PixelArray() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 5));
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bi);
        for (int yy = 0; yy < labels[0].length; yy++) {
            for (int xx = 0; xx < labels.length; xx++) {
                JLabel l = new JLabel(icon);
                labels[xx][yy] = l;
                l.setOpaque(true);
                add(l);
            }
        }
    }

    public void updatePixels(boolean[][] bools) {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < labels.length; xx++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < labels[0].length; yy++) {
                JLabel l = labels[xx][yy];
                if (bools[xx][yy]) {
                    l.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    l.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```